# Identity4Server many SPA clients best approach?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, single-page-application, identityserver4

Hi I have inherit a system like this:

An Api and many Fronts (spas) they share a common menu with links to navigate to each others but they are different react apps, with different urls. And Azure Active directory to authenticate an the Api is protected with Bearer token.

Something like this:

[image]

Now I have authorization requirements with a custom permissions that the business people want to assign to every user, for actions that they can do or not and visibility things.

I want to use Identity4Server with the active directory as an open id provider. Then consume a provider api to get custom permission and put those permissions in the claims. Then in the Api impl policies that demand for specify roles and claims to accomplish the permissions specifications.

Something like this:

[image]

Identity4Server config:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenID Connect", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/";
                    options.ClientId = "ClientId";
                    options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name",
                        RoleClaimType = "role"
                    };
                });
```

Api:

```
services
                .AddAuthentication(configure =>
                {
                    configure.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    configure.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Audience = "api";
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                });

var clientsPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Bearer")
                .AddRequirements(new ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement("ClientsModule", new[] { "1" }))
                .RequireRole("Admin")
                .Build();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Clients", clientsPolicy);
            });
```

For the react apps I'm using this npm "oidc-client": "1.7.0" and a similar approach to https://medium.com/@franciscopa91/how-to-implement-oidc-authentication-with-react-context-api-and-react-router-205e13f2d49
And the Clients config is: (Provider its quite similar the only thing that change is url localhost:3001)

```
export const IDENTITY_CONFIG = {
    authority: "http://localhost:5000",
    clientId: "fronts",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/signin-oidc",
    login: "http://localhost:5000/login",
    automaticSilentRenew: false,
    loadUserInfo: false,
    silent_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/silentrenew",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/signout-callback-oidc",
    audience: "fronts",
    responseType: "id_token token",
    grantType: "password",
    scope: "openid api",
    webAuthResponseType: "id_token token"
};
```

If the user login into clients (localhost:3000) front and then navigate to providers (localhost:3001) front it shouldn't login again. To accomplish this I configure all the fronts with the same client id, but I don't know if this is the correct way to do it. Now my config class in identity server is:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "fronts",
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    ClientName = "All fronts",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/signin-oidc", "http://localhost:3001/signin-oidc" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/signout-callback-oidc", "http://localhost:3001/signout-callback-oidc" },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3001" },

                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "api"
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

Do you think this configuration is the correct way to do it or there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned

> many different react apps, with different urls

but in your code snippet I see only the `Clients(localhost:3000)`.

Anyway, the protocol spec tells us to register as many clients as we need. SSO is the main responsibility of identity provider.

You just need to add `RequireConsent = false;` to your client def in IdSrv to avoid additional unintended user interaction.

Additionally, nowadays the recommended auth flow for spa-s is "code+pkce". You can take a look at [this article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/Migrating-oidc-client-js-to-use-the-OpenID-Connect-Authorization-Code-Flow-and-PKCE) in order to get detailed info for transition.

Comment: hi d_f thank you for your reply. I will take a look at the article. You can also see Providers(localhost:3001) with different url. Im going to update the question with the spa identity configuration. Also the problem is not register many clients, I can register 1 client per spa site, the problem is if I login in one site and navigate to other site I dont have to make login again.

Comment: Sure! As I mentioned, that's the main job for IdP to create a session for a user and perform login silently for each next app, acting on behalf of the same user.

Comment: You need to add `RequireConsent = false;` to your client def in IdSrv to avoid additional unintended user interaction. Will add this to the answer.

Comment: One more minor thing: `ClientSecret` is not required for Implicit nor Code+PKCE grant type. `ClientSecret` has to be persisted secretly, while browser-based apps code is public by design.